# Votifier PHP Encryption

Tags: php, encryption, rsa, minecraft

I've been trying to add votifier functionality to my site but so far, without any luck at all.
My problem is that the encryption using the openssl_public_encrypt returns an empty response.

Here's my code: http://pastebin.com/wakjcxSF
I call it like this:

```
$vote = new Vote(USERNAME, SERVERIP, SERVERPORT, VOTIFIERKEY);
$vote->castVote();
```

The output of the print_r:

```
0

VOTE Something test 127.0.0.1 1376050280 
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY----- MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAiRda9+W9mXLz1Mvc4hXMo rea2NPPJVgbQCypwpgIUK0Q7vQ2sK+Om2yCyTtwIvdOCAa1Uh+cX2Drs3xHkPutw/ rkTiFEWWQ3ol3jxMm+5BXUSESSK+P26nr7JvFddnOdVM1FFVCwFXYmYIwigeXK3lO qrOLFdxVEbpG5wEcNPOVIqq1RKfKQIFGvYfIVpRCaj3yMRlSK4S1jQtlqMy5Tnva+ xqaFjEHN2QJRwLecmkPnGsWicEfoc+khV64/06YKg5Becqx69sS+snY8SM1E/atZk     b/eqm165A7Awzw3e9Fl2Uk4F7kUwrRGZDjzu6knr6Vr13slXDxzEKd33xv8/QIDAQ AB -----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Original public key:

```
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAiRda9+W9mXLz1Mvc4hXMorea2NPPJVgbQCypwpgIUK0Q7vQ2sK+Om2yCyTtwIvdOCAa1Uh+cX2Drs3xHkPutw/rkTiFEWWQ3ol3jxMm+5BXUSESSK+P26nr7JvFddnOdVM1FFVCwFXYmYIwigeXK3lOqrOLFdxVEbpG5wEcNPOVIqq1RKfKQIFGvYfIVpRCaj3yMRlSK4S1jQtlqMy5Tnva+xqaFjEHN2QJRwLecmkPnGsWicEfoc+khV64/06YKg5Becqx69sS+snY8SM1E/atZkb/eqm165A7Awzw3e9Fl2Uk4F7kUwrRGZDjzu6knr6Vr13slXDxzEKd33xv8/QIDAQAB
```

I used this tutorial: http://topg.org/php_votifier.

I tried to look around on google but the problems was invalid key problems. Result:
google (com)/search?q=Votifier+PHP+Encryption&oq=Votifier+PHP+Encryption&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i60j69i62l2.6301j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=917b53cc1ec39b52&q=Votifier+PHP+Encryption
Found this too: teamavolition (com)/topic/14380-solved-php-rsa-encryptions-votifier/

Best Regards,
- ImThatPedoBear

Answer (score 0):

That's sorta a "naked" RSA public key. OpenSSL only works with public keys that are in an X.509 cert.

My recommendation would be to use [phpseclib's Crypt_RSA](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/). eg.

```
<?php
include('Crypt/RSA.php');

$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
$rsa->loadKey('...'); // public key

$plaintext = '...';

//$rsa->setEncryptionMode(CRYPT_RSA_ENCRYPTION_OAEP);
$ciphertext = $rsa->encrypt($plaintext);
```